# No module named 'wikiSearch'

Tags: import, wikipedia, modulenotfounderror

i a using a github code where i have to import  wiki search as

**'import wikiSearch, ngram_gen'**

and this is giving me the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikiSearch'
i have tried
pip install wikipedia
already

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do `import wikipedia` instead? That's what they do in [their example](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/).

BTW are you sure you want to use this module? It seems quite outdated, the last release was in 2014.

Comment: i am doing a problem related to hierarchical document cluster labeling improvement .. so i was basically trying to run some old algorithms first is there anything new which i can use instead of wiki search ?